# What is a person who rides on camel-back called?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A person who rides on horse-back is called equestrian.

I came across the following guidelines:

> "Camel Ride Guidelines:
>
> XXXXXXXX
>
> We will do all we can to accommodate **riders**, however, safety is our first priority. Below are general restrictions for safety and compliance  with USDA regulations:
>
> - A single **rider** may be paired with another single **rider** in line at the operators discretion.
> - Pregnant woman are not permitted to ride the camels.
> - People with back or hip injuries should not ride the camels.
> - **Riders** may not choose which camel they ride.
>     Two adults are not permitted to ride together on any of the camels."
>
> Link: https://louisvillezoo.org/plan/rides-attractions/camel-rides/

Here the people who intend to ride on camel-back are referred to as **camel riders** (or simply **riders**). We all know that a person who rides on horse-back is called equestrian.

Is there an equivalent word for a person who rides on camel-back?

Comment: This is going to be disappointing but *equestrian* comes to us from the Latin nominative singular *eques* (horseback rider), and the genus name for horses is *equus*; similarly the genus name for camels is *camelus*, so analogously the "knights who ride camels" (camelback riders) would (ostensibly) be *cameles*, and thus imported into English as *camelestrian*. The reason *equestrian* sounds fancy to us is because the quotidian name we have for the specifies is *horse*, not derived from the Latin, but *camelestrian* sounds banal because we use the same word for *camel* as our Roman forebears.

Comment: What is a person who rides on camel-back called?  Crazy: those things spit!  (No, this is not a serious answer...)

Comment: It may be worth noting that when horseback rides are offered in the same sort of context, the people riding would almost certainly NOT be referred to as equestrians, except perhaps as a joke (at their expense).

Comment: Off topic but isn't there a contradiction between the rules: **Rule#1**_"A single rider may be paired with another single rider"_ and **Rule#2** _"Two adults are not permitted to ride together on any of the camels."_ unless of course Rule #1 applies only when non-adult riders are involved. In which case it is a pretty bad way of phrasing the Rule in the first place.

Comment: @curious_cat. Apparently, you are correct. But, in reading rules, you should not first try to find out the contradictions. You are, going by the principles of interpretation, required to read the rules so as to bring about a harmony between two or more apparently contradicting rules. This is, in short, called "harmonious construction" of rules.The instant rules, if so constructed, would mean that two riders are allowed, when one of them is non-adult. Hope this makes the thing clear.

Comment: why is such a word necessary in the first place? What is wrong with camel rider to start with?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Nothing wrong with "camel rider". Of course, nothing wrong with "horse rider". But, there is a specific word - "equestrian" - for "horse rider". This is richness of the language. This is where we all get interest in exploring this treasure.

Comment: Can you think of any downside to this so called richness. Do we really need 10 different ways to say the exact "horse rider?" Certainly we can attach minor nuances to the meanings of  those 10 words.  If 10 is not enough, how about 20, 30 or even 100? There got to be argument against having that many words equivalent words, right? :-) This does not just apply to this particular discussion, but to the language as a whole :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**cameleer**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cameleer)

> 1. a camel driver

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cameleer)

> 1. Camel driver or rider, one who travels by camel.

[Oxford English dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cameleer)

> A person who controls or rides a camel.

[American Heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cameleer)

> A person who drives or rides a camel.

As you can see in the definitions, **camel driver** is another alternative, although this is more used for people with multiple camels:

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=camel%20driver)

> camel driver: (person who leads or herds camels)

Comment: Gee, I would have said "cameleon".

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes they are called mahouts. However, this term is usually reserved for those who ride elephants.

My sources are the news media of Oman: http://omanobserver.om/training-for-camel-mahouts/

And the ever-indomitable google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=mahout+google+books&oq=mahout+google+books&aqs=chrome..69i57.1689597j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22camel+mahout%22

Comment: "Mahout" is the word for the person who controls an elephant. He may not be a rider.

Comment: Just to supply some evidence that in fact the word is sometimes appropriate: http://omanobserver.om/training-for-camel-mahouts/

Comment: I upvoted your answer; here's a google search of "camel mahout" that shows this does indeed describe camel riders: https://www.google.com/search?q=mahout+google+books&oq=mahout+google+books&aqs=chrome..69i57.1689597j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22camel+mahout%22  perhaps you should edit your answer with quotes of these instances so it isn't deleted for lack of evidence.

Comment: I may, if circumstances require it

Comment: @V0ight. Believe me, mahouts are those who keep elephants, feed them, take care of them and control them during elephant-ride. In India, people have the calling of offering their elephants for pleasure-ride. While a rider enjoys the ride, the mahout walks along the elephant controlling it. Riding is not the principal activity of a mahout. Of course, he may, in controlling the elephant, ride the elephant.

Comment: It is possible for one word to have different uses in different situations and cultures. I am accustomed to hearing those who ride elephants not as passengers but also as controllers called mahouts.

Comment: Please explain why you have a problem with editing your answer to include a reference which you have found and/or a reference which @V0ight contributed.  You have what could be a good, complete answer, but you seem to be saying that we should just take your word for a definition of this esoteric term, esoterically used.  Having defintions scattered in the comments is not an adequate substitute for including them in the answer.

Comment: Because it isn't required, because I know my answer is right and will be borne out by independent research, and because I am *lazy, slothful, lackadaisical, indolent*, and *unhurried*.

Given the amount of time I put into this answer, perhaps I should also add that I appear to be a little *bellicose*.

Comment: But can you be bribed, or encouraged or nudged?  Put in at least one of the references, and I will retract my downvote.  Put in both and I will (if I can, and I think I can) also upvote.  Can you be bought for 12 rep points?  (And possibly hordes of users will upvote a complete answer.)

Comment: With greed and avaricious ambition in my eyes, dreaming of the multitudinous thousands which might come flocking to my post in search of the one true answer to the immortal question of the dromedary's master, I dropped on both links, chuckling and rubbing my hands greedily in anticipation of the ill-gotten gains.

Comment: And didn't it feel good to do right?  Downvote retracted and upvote accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

While in Iraq I heard the term Janjaweed used. But I believe that it translates to an arab with a gun riding a mount. thats the closest name ive ever heard for someone riding on camelback.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the word *sandaniswar* (सांडणी स्वार), but I'm not sure of its origin and meaning.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide some references to your answer?

Comment: Is this an English word? It appears to be Hindu or some other Indian language.